# Fedora 27 - unable to boot, grub error?

Tags: linux, fedora, grub2, uefi

I just performed a fresh, clean install of Fedora 27 five days ago.  Upon a reboot from an update cycle via DNF, I am unable to boot normally or into rescue mode.

At the grub menu, I have a generic kernel listed and no idea where it came from or how to fix this.  No matter which kernel I select whether I try to enter rescue mode, it drops me into emergency mode.  (see the link at the bottom)

generic (4.13.13-300.fc27.x86_64)
Fedora (4.13.12-300.fc27.x86_64) 27 (Workstation Edition)
Fedora (4.13.13-300.fc27.x86_64) "                       " 
Fedora (0-rescue ...           ) "                       "

This occurred last week when I was running Fedora 26 as well ... 
https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/112345/fedora-boot-label-error-entering-emergency-modeexit-the-shell-to-continue/

Any ideas folks or how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Enter into the rescue mode, check for the grub files and check the fstab entry. As this happened with me as well and the /boot was not mounted correctly, so making changes in fstab and doing a mount -a resolved my issue.

Comment: Hi Divyani, I am unable to enter rescue mode no matter which kernel I select to edit for boot.  It drops me into emergency mode each and every time.  While not a neophyte to Linux, I am somewhat rusty when it comes to troubleshooting boot issues.  I could very well be doing something incorrectly.  Can you lay out the steps for me?  Thank you.

Comment: Hi, Did you tried Booting into a Fedora Live DVD/USB
After the load, open a terminal,
Press Ctrl+Alt+T
Run in it:

sudo -i
fdisk -l
Fdisk will inform you as your partition / (root) called, say it as in the post /dev/sdb1, continuous running:
umount /dev/sdb1
fsck -y /dev/sdb1
reboot
Remove the DVD/USB and boot from the SDD